# Which definition of 'set' in 'offset' and 'set ... off'?

Tags: verbs

I already understand and so ask NOT about the definitions of

> [**offset**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/offset) = 1. [with object] Counteract (something) by having an equal and opposite force or effect:
>
> **[set someone against](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/set)** = Cause someone to be in opposition or conflict with
>
> **set something against** = Offset something against

, but instead want to dredge below. Which definition of **[set](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/set)** applies? How does the juxtaposition of off + set imply/effect/produce these definitions?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about learning English.

Comment: Definitions aren't necessarily componential - you can't get _dredge_ from _offset_ +/- _set against_.

Comment: @jimsug Sorry, I don't understand what you mean? I'm not asking about *dredge*.

Comment: I'm not clear on the question, but if you are asking about the word 'set', in this context it refers to position or place rather than a group.

Comment: @UpvoteLawArea51Proposal I don't know what you mean either, then. It seems like others aren't either. This question is in danger of being closed because it's unclear.

Comment: Although in my second attempt at reading your question, you're asking how _off + set_ and _set + against_ can produce these meanings? This is a question for [English.se]

Comment: @jimsug Yes, that's what I mean. I asked here in case that ELU deems these words not complex enough.

Comment: This question is about *etymology*. The OP should consult an etymological dictionary, such as the OED.

Comment: It's not really about etymology, but about usage... particles tend to colocate with certain verbs frequently, until the disparate meanings and the collective meaning have drifted such that they are no longer retrievable by the modern speaker - it's about _usage_ and _etymology_ the latter of which is beyond the scope of this stack. Please consult a dictionary or ask on ELU. Why do you prefer to spend our time instead of theirs?

Comment: I understood the OP to be asking which meaning of "set" is in effect in the verb "offset"; the OP wanted to "dredge below", which sounds to me like a colorful way of asking about a word's etymology. The OED devotes pages and pages to the verb *set*.

Answer (score 1):

I believe your question is:  The phrases "offset" and "to set against" both use the root word "set", but the definition of set in these phrases is unclear.  I would like to *dig deeper* on this.

In both cases, set is being used to indicate a deliberate placement of an object, person, or force.  This is similar to a craftsman making a deliberate choice when crafting an object. Definition 2 at your link seems to cover this usage.

> Thanks. Please also explain 'off' and how it generated these meanings?

Think about phrases like "on target", "on the mark", or "on the line".  In these phrases, "on" means to place precisely at a location. Conversely, "off target" or "off the mark" both mean to place something somewhere other than the location.

In the case of "offset", the "off" is used in this sense - there is an expected location, and the subject is intentionally placed somewhere else.  Consider this example of [offset printing](http://fc00.deviantart.net/fs70/i/2011/133/4/c/offset_lithography_info_poster_by_samisad0rk-d3g95ks.png). The colored text is deliberately set to miss the expected location for effect.

When you are talking about opposing forces, it is useful to think of something in balance.  For instance, a tray of drinks.  If you have six drinks on one side of the tray, it may tip and fall.  By placing something heavy on the other side of the tray, you offset the weight of the drinks and balance the tray.  In this case, you are not putting your heavy thing in the center of the tray - you are setting it off center to balance the drinks.

Comment: Thanks. Please also explain 'off' and how it generated these meanings?

Comment: Will you please to respond in your answer, and not as a comment?

Comment: @UpvoteLawArea51Proposal Please don't leave stock comments like "Will you please to respond in your answer, and not as a comment?" on every answer you receive.